# any way to decrease the amount of togTriggers needed?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm using the following script to open a box on mouse-over and click.
On my page there are a lot of boxes to be opened, with much more to come.
The only way i could make these boxes work is for every box to make a new togTrigger. Even when the same word opens the same box on a different place on the page, i need a new togTrigger. Eventually i will end up with togTrigger1 to togTrigger200 or something. Which is not very practical.
Any way to reduce the amount of togTriggers needed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- HIDE FROM OLD BROWSERS
    /* <![CDATA[ */

    var oVTog = {
        toggle: function (el) {
            var container = el.parentNode;
            var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
            para.style.display = "none";

            var isClicked = false;

            el.onmouseover = function () {
                para.style.display = '';
                return false;
            };
            el.onmouseout = function () {
                if (!isClicked)
                    para.style.display = 'none';
                return false;
            };
            el.onclick = function () {
                // if it's clicked, change it to TRUE
                // if it's clicked again, change it back to FALSE

                isClicked = !isClicked; // toggle

                para.style.display = ((isClicked) ? '' : 'none');
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
    window.onload = function () {
        var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger2');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger3');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger4');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger5');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger6');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger7');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger8');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger9');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger10');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger11');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
    };

    /* ]]> */
    //END HIDING -->
</script>
```

this is how i apply the script in the body within a div (the page is made out of many divs within a table, /p should not be within a div though, but it is working):

```
<a href="#" id="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
       <p class="togContent">
        text
        </p>
```

when there are two or more textboxes within the same div, the other togTriggers are within a span:

```
<span><a href="#" id="togTrigger4"><i>text</i></a>
       <p class="togContent">
        text
        </p></span>
```

Comment: What about selecting by class, rather than id? That is to say, what if you instead make all of the id='togTriggerXX' elements into class='togTrigger'. You could then use document.querySelectorAll('.togTrigger') or document.getElementsByClassName('togTrigger') (The advantage to the first one being that you can call it on a container element, so you only target elements contained within it. You could also call it on the document element, using '#idContainer .toggleTriggerClassName') You would then get a nodeList. You could iterate through the list, calling oVTog.toggle on each element.

Comment: I would need a code example for that because my knowledge of javascript is very limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, and as Matt pointed out more clearly, you can access the elements programatically - there's no need to refer to them all by name. Here's some code that does the trick. (You can ignore the first contents of the first script tag - they're helper functions I have in my 'blank.html' file - the file that all (my) pages grow from)

Javascript arrays offer you the forEach function, unfortunately, NodeLists don't.
You can see how I've made use of it in myInit2. While this example is somewhat contrived - there's only a single thing happening to each element, I've found it to be a useful pattern - albeit without the anonymous (unnamed) function that is called on each node in the NodeList.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- HIDE FROM OLD BROWSERS
    /* <![CDATA[ */

    var oVTog = {
        toggle: function (el) {
            var container = el.parentNode;
            var para = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
            para.style.display = "none";

            var isClicked = false;

            el.onmouseover = function () {
                para.style.display = '';
                return false;
            };
            el.onmouseout = function () {
                if (!isClicked)
                    para.style.display = 'none';
                return false;
            };
            el.onclick = function () {
                // if it's clicked, change it to TRUE
                // if it's clicked again, change it back to FALSE

                isClicked = !isClicked; // toggle

                para.style.display = ((isClicked) ? '' : 'none');
                return false;
            };
        }
    };


    window.addEventListener('load', yourInit, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false);
    window.addEventListener('load', myInit2, false);

    function yourInit() 
    {
        // 2 lines per element to toggle. 200items = 400 lines
        var l;
        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
        oVTog.toggle(l);

        l = document.getElementById('togTrigger4');
        oVTog.toggle(l);
    };

    function myInit() 
    {
        // 4 lines total. 200items = 4 lines
        var containerDiv = document.getElementById('myMethod');
        var i, nodeList = containerDiv.getElementsByClassName('togTrigger');
        for (i=0; i<nodeList.length; i++)
            oVTog.toggle(nodeList[i]);
    };

    function myInit2() 
    {
        var containerDiv = document.getElementById('mySecondMethod');
        var i, nodeList = containerDiv.getElementsByClassName('togTrigger');
        forEachNode(
                        nodeList, 
                        function(curItem, curIndex, ndeLst)
                        { 
                            oVTog.toggle(curItem) 
                        }
                    );
    };


    /* ]]> */
    //END HIDING -->
</script>

<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='yourMethod'>
        <a href="#" id="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
        <p class="togContent">text</p>

        <span>
            <a href="#" id="togTrigger4"><i>text</i></a>
            <p class="togContent">text</p>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id='myMethod'>
        <a href="#" class="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
        <p class="togContent">text</p>

        <span>
            <a href="#" class="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
            <p class="togContent">text</p>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id='mySecondMethod'>
        <a href="#" class="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
        <p class="togContent">text</p>

        <span>
            <a href="#" class="togTrigger"><i>text</i></a>
            <p class="togContent">text</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop:

```
// Handle the first one separately because it doesn't have  a number at the end
var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger'); 
oVTog.toggle(l);
for (var i=2;i< 12;i++){
    l = document.getElementById('togTrigger' + i);
    oVTog.toggle(l);
}
```

Also consider assigning a class to all togTrigger elements, select them, loop over them and call `oVTog.toggle`.

Comment: Thanks, do i change anything besides the number 12 if the number of elements reach 3 digits?
edit: it doesn't work, all the boxes are now open

Comment: @Martijn No, it's the same with 3 digits. It should do the same as the code that you posted, was it working before?

Comment: I edited my question to show how i apply the script within the html